# How does nlme calculate denominator degrees of freedom?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

This is heteroskedastic model I used:

```
fit<-nmle::lme(fixed=Y ~ trt, random=~(0+trt)|clst, 
             weights=varIdent(form=~1|trt), 
             method ="REML", data=x)
```

For this model, I want to write a function returning p value with different methods to calculate denominator degrees of freedom(default, Satterthwaite, Kenward-Roger etc). I tried `anova.lme(fit)` but I didn't understand how the denDF was calculated here and how to do Satterthwaite or Kenward-Roger.

(I have written a function for homoskedastic model...now I want to do similar thing for heteroskedastic model in `nmle`.)

````
homo.p<-function(x, ddf=NA){

  if (is.na(ddf)){
    #Default: use normal distribution to calculate p-value
    fit<-lme4::lmer(Y~trt+trt*(1|clst),data = x)
    return(
      pnorm(summary(fit)$coefficients[2,3],lower.tail = F)
      )
  }else if(ddf %in% c("Satterthwaite", "Kenward-Roger")){
    #use Satterswaite or Kenward-Roger to calculate p-value 
    fit<-lmerTest::lmer(Y~trt+trt*(1|clst),data = x)
    return(
      anova(fit,ddf=ddf)[6]
      )
  }


}
```
````